# Internet Access not working in Android 1.6, but works in 2.0/2.1/2.2

Tags: android, permissions, jsoup

I'm trying to parse some html using jsoup (1.3.3) in my android activity. When I call this code

```
Jsoup.connect("http://www.google.com").get();
```

It works fine in android 2.1 and 2.2 but in 1.6 I get a "java.io.IOException: 403 Error loading URL".

I'm using the emulator to test this and I've noticed that admob ads are also not showing in 1.6 but they work in 2.0, 2.1 and 2.2.

Using the web browser in the 1.6 emulator does work so I'm pretty confident the problem is in my code somewhere.

Is there some extra permission I need for internet access in 1.6 that you don't need in 2.0+?

This is how my manifest file is structured, does the position of the uses-permission tag have any effect?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.foo.bar"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0"
  android:installLocation="auto">

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
android:label="@string/app_name" 
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" 
android:name="blahblah" 
android:description="@string/app_desc">

    <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".activities.MainMenu">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

<activity android:name=".activities.FullList" android:label="@string/app_name"/>

<!-- The application's publisher ID assigned by AdMob -->
<meta-data android:value="blahblahblah" android:name="ADMOB_PUBLISHER_ID" />

</application>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

</manifest>
```

I've tried creating a new project from scratch with just a hello world screen that uses the Jsoup.connect() method and that works fine on the same 1.6 emulator, so it must be a code problem but I can't figure it out.

Comment: What permissions are in your AndroidManifest.xml? Also have you tried using straight HttpClient to hit the URL (getting Jsoup out of the loop)?

Comment: The code `Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.google.com").get(); Log.i("jsoup", doc.title());` works for me on the 1.6 emulator with `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` and *jsoup-1.3.3.jar*

Comment: Have you verified with another app such as the default browser that networking works in that emulator instance?   Might want to make a new emulator just to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSOUP internally uses [HttpURLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html). Here is the [line throwing exception](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jsoup/helper/HttpConnection.java#L327).

The internet connection is OK (or else it would throw exception earlier) and you are getting a reply from server which is: [403 HTTP FORBIDDEN](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#HTTP_FORBIDDEN)

Is there some kind of login in place? Do check that you can open the same URL in browser on the same device/emulator.

Comment: I'm looking to update jsoup.connect so that one can set it to not throw an exception on non-200 responses, and get a server response code out of the response object. That should make this case clearer to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Try inserting /uses-sdk near the end of the script or try deleting /uses-permission with each surrounded with angle brackets

Answer (score 0):

> I've tried creating a new project from scratch with just a hello world screen that uses the Jsoup.connect() method and that works fine on the same 1.6 emulator, so it must be a code problem but I can't figure it out.

Try putting a test usage of this early in your application startup (or if that causes an ANR timeout, add a "test" button)

Make a copy of your application and comment a lot of things out

Somewhere between your minimal test which works and your full application which doesn't, there lies an important difference.  Recursively divide the difference and conquer it...